# Random 403 Errors

Tags: .htaccess-configuration, server, apache, error-pages

I have a joomla site installed in a subdomain and have moved it to another folder within the same subdomain. However, I am getting random 403 errors (not able to reproduce yet) and I seem to see it if I go AFK for a long period of time then go back to visit the site.

Note: This site requires you to be logged in to view any of the pages (Registered access).

Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks.

Update: After sifting through a few apache logs, it looks like the only 403 errors in here are as follows: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 6616 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Those 403 are on pages you are browsing, or for assets like css, js, images files etc?

Comment: Still looking for help on this. Please let me know if you need additional http header information? Thanks. Note: I do have SSL integrated (but did not while in development and migration); could this be an issue somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Those 403 are on pages you are browsing, or for assets like css, js, images files etc?

403 error means, that access is forbidden for the requested file.

Since you moved your site:

- Check your htaccess file for any possible required modifications, to match your site's new location.
- Those 403 errors, can be on requests for external to your joomla site files, that you didn't move, and now they can't be found. This with a combination of directives in your htaccess/server could result to 403 error instead of 404.

These are my quickest ideas for now... 
It could help us more, if you could share urls and urls for forbidden pages/files, and parts of your htaccess with info pertaining to your hosting location.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the assets or images, etc. Everything functions fine but I get random 403's as if I am not logged in anymore sometimes (usually after logging in, waiting, and then clicking on another page). Note:  All pages are restricted to being visible by members of the site only.

Comment: Still need some help on this, how can I give you the details of the htaccess file? Too long to post here.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't get the code from htaccess to fit in here - nor could I get it to format correctly. Anyway, you can see my htaccess here: https://paste.ee/p/IDP5b

Comment: @user1721449 Your htaccess seems ok. Did you manage to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I have not. But I turned caching off and set the session lifetime to be longer thinking it might have been a session issue. However, now I have a user telling me that he hit a 403 before logging into the front-end (site requires you to log in to view anything aka Registered access).

Comment: Apache log: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 444 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Update: Have been sniffing around with fiddler and am still not hitting any 403 errors (in private mode via firefox and chrome). What could my users be getting 403 errors on?

Comment: Sniffing around, it looks like users are getting 403'd from thinking they are not logged in? 

Response Headers
Date: Sat, 30 Apr 2016 02:15:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.31
X-Logged-In: False